# How to Export React Icons Using Functional Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, icons

Error I am getting: `./src/components/IconsOne.js Attempted import error: 'TiHome' is not exported from 'react-icons/fa'.`

IconsOne.js:

```
import { TiHome } from 'react-icons/fa';

const IconsOne = () => {
    return (
        <div className="homeIcon">
            <h3>
                <TiHome />
            </h3>
        </div>
    )
}

export default IconsOne
```

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import IconsOne from "./components/IconsOne";


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <IconsOne />
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I am trying to build a navbar and the first step is to render a home icon. I used this page for documentation on importing icons for react: *https://react-icons.github.io/react-icons/* and the name of the Icon that I'm trying to import is **TiHome**

The link to the icon is: **https://react-icons.github.io/react-icons/search?q=tihome**
Thank you.

Comment: Is the icon really called "TiHome"? Because it says that the particular icon is not exported from the font awesome collection.

Comment: @FireFighter Yes, here is the link: https://react-icons.github.io/react-icons/search?q=tihome

Comment: But then it is probably exported from 'react-icons' and not 'react-icons/fa'.

Comment: @FireFighter Okay thank you. I didn't know where to look to figure this out, but that makes sense. THank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is `fa`, that is not the path for Typicons but for FontAwesome, so if you want TiHome from Typicons then according to react-icons you must use instead the `ti` path, so:

```
import { TiHome } from 'react-icons/ti';

const IconsOne = () => {
    return (
        <div className="homeIcon">
            <h3>
                <TiHome />
            </h3>
        </div>
    )
}

export default IconsOne
```